# Traefik with Let's Encrypt

Tags: docker, docker-compose, lets-encrypt, traefik

I am trying to use Let's Encrypt with Traefic, but no matter how I set things up I always get the error `msg="http: TLS handshake error from 193.174.362.742:65260: remote error: tls: bad certificate"` with the browser saying the certificate is only valid for traefik default. In addition I cannot get it to redirect http traffic to https. When I use http the site loads as normal instead of redirecting and using https.

If I connect to the traefik container I can see the acme.json file is there, but it is always empty.

I have run out of ideas for new things to try. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik
    networks:
      - ${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_NETWORK?Variable not set}
      - default
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - volume_traefik:/letsencrypt
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    command:
      # Enable Docker in Traefik, so that it reads labels from Docker services
      - --providers.docker
      # Add a constraint to only use services with the label for this stack
      # from the env var TRAEFIK_TAG
      - --providers.docker.constraints=Label(`traefik.constraint-label-stack`, `${TRAEFIK_TAG?Variable not set}`)
      # Do not expose all Docker services, only the ones explicitly exposed
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false

      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.web-secured.address=:443

      - --certificatesResolvers.le.acme.email=${LETS_ENCRYPT_EMAIL?Variable not set}
      - --certificatesResolvers.le.acme.storage=letsencrypt/acme.json
      - --certificatesResolvers.le.acme.httpChallenge=true
      - --certificatesResolvers.le.acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_NETWORK?Veriable not set}

      # Enable the access log, with HTTP requests
      - --accesslog
      # Enable the Traefik log, for configurations and errors
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --log
      # Enable the Dashboard and API
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --api
    labels:
      # Enable Traefik for this service, to make it available in the public network
      - traefik.enable=true
      # Use the traefik-public network (declared below)
      - traefik.docker.network=${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_NETWORK?Variable not set}
      # Use the custom label "traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public"
      # This public Traefik will only use services with this label
      - traefik.constraint-label=${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_TAG?Variable not set}
      # traefik-http set up only to use the middleware to redirect to https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
      # Handle host with and without "www" to redirect to only one of them
      # Uses environment variable DOMAIN
      # To disable www redirection remove the Host() you want to discard, here and
      # below for HTTPS
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-http.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`) || Host(`www.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-http.entrypoints=http
      # traefik-https the actual router using HTTPS
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`) || Host(`www.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.tls=true
      # Use the "le" (Let's Encrypt) resolver created below
      #- traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.tls.certresolver={$TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_NETWORK?Variable not set}
      #- traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.tls.certresolver=le
      # Define the port inside of the Docker service to use
      - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy.loadbalancer.server.port=80
      # Handle domain with and without "www" to redirect to only one
      # To disable www redirection remove the next line
      - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect.redirectregex.regex=^https?://(www.)?(${DOMAIN?Variable not set})/(.*)
      # Redirect a domain with www to non-www
      # To disable it remove the next line
      - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect.redirectregex.replacement=https://${DOMAIN?Variable not set}/$${3}
      # Redirect a domain without www to www
      # To enable it remove the previous line and uncomment the next
      # - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME}-www-redirect.redirectregex.replacement=https://www.${DOMAIN}/$${3}
      # Middleware to redirect www, to disable it remove the next line 
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.middlewares=${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect
      # Middleware to redirect www, and redirect HTTP to HTTPS
      # to disable www redirection remove the section: ${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect,
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-http.middlewares=${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect,${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-https-redirect

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: "test-postgres"
    volumes:
      - app-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  backend:
    image: backend:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.constraint-label-stack=${TRAEFIK_TAG?Variable not set}
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-http.rule=PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/docs`) || PathPrefix(`/redoc`)
      - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend.loadbalancer.server.port=443
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend.tls=true

  frontend:
    image: frontend:latest
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.constraint-label-stack=${TRAEFIK_TAG?Variable not set}
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-http.rule=PathPrefix(`/`)
      - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=443
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend.tls=true


volumes:
  app-db-data:
  volume_traefik:

networks:
  traefik-public:
    # Allow setting it to false for testing
    external: ${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_NETWORK_IS_EXTERNAL-true}
```

Edit: I now have Let's Encrypt working, but still am not able to get www addresses to forward to non www addresses.

```
version: "3.7"
    services:
      proxy:
        image: traefik
        networks:
          - ${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_NETWORK?Variable not set}
          - default
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
          - volume_traefik:/letsencrypt
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
          - "8080:8080"
        command:
          # Enable Docker in Traefik, so that it reads labels from Docker services
          - --providers.docker
          # Add a constraint to only use services with the label for this stack
          # from the env var TRAEFIK_TAG
          - --providers.docker.constraints=Label(`traefik.constraint-label-stack`, `${TRAEFIK_TAG?Variable not set}`)
          # Do not expose all Docker services, only the ones explicitly exposed
          - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false

          - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
          - --entrypoints.web-secured.address=:443
          - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure
          - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https
          - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
          - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.certResolver=le
          - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.domains[0].main=${DOMAIN?Variable not set}

          - --certificatesResolvers.le.acme.email=${LETS_ENCRYPT_EMAIL?Variable not set}
          - --certificatesResolvers.le.acme.storage=letsencrypt/acme.json
          - --certificatesResolvers.le.acme.httpChallenge=true
          - --certificatesResolvers.le.acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_NETWORK?Veriable not set}

          # Enable the access log, with HTTP requests
          - --accesslog
          # Enable the Traefik log, for configurations and errors
          - --log.level=DEBUG
          - --log
          # Enable the Dashboard and API
          - --api.dashboard=true
          - --api
        labels:
          - traefik.enable=true
          - traefik.docker.network=${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_NETWORK?Variable not set}
          - traefik.constraint-label=${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_TAG?Variable not set}
          - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
          - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
          - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-http.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`) || Host(`www.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
          - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-http.entrypoints=http
          - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`) || Host(`www.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
          - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.entrypoints=https
          - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.tls=true
          - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.tls.certresolver=le
          - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy.loadbalancer.server.port=80
          - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect.redirectregex.regex=^https?://(www.)?(${DOMAIN?Variable not set})/(.*)
          - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect.redirectregex.replacement=https://${DOMAIN?Variable not set}/$${3}

          - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.middlewares=${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect
          - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-http.middlewares=${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect,${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-https-redirect

      db:
        image: postgres:latest
        container_name: "test-postgres"
        volumes:
          - app-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        env_file:
          - .env
        environment:
          - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        ports:
          - "5432:5432"

      backend:
        image: backend:latest
        depends_on:
          - db
        env_file:
          - .env
        build:
          context: ./backend
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        labels:
          - traefik.enable=true
          - traefik.constraint-label-stack=${TRAEFIK_TAG?Variable not set}
          - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-http.rule=PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/docs`) || PathPrefix(`/redoc`)
          - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend.loadbalancer.server.port=443
          - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend.tls=true

      frontend:
        image: frontend:latest
        build:
          context: ./frontend
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        labels:
          - traefik.enable=true
          - traefik.constraint-label-stack=${TRAEFIK_TAG?Variable not set}
          - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-http.rule=PathPrefix(`/`)
          - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=443
          - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend.tls=true


    volumes:
      app-db-data:
      volume_traefik:

    networks:
      traefik-public:
        # Allow setting it to false for testing
        external: ${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_NETWORK_IS_EXTERNAL-true}
```

Comment: Let's encrypt works only when your domain is registered with an external IP. I'm guessing you are trying this on the local machine,  which will eventually fail. Try deploying this on any cloud instance like aws ec2 and register its external ip with dns name on noip.com and try.

Comment: I am using an external IP. I finally got Let's encrypt working and forwarding http to https, but I am still not able to get it to forward www addresses to non www addresses.

Comment: configure the subdomain regex route like this `"HostRegexp(`{sub:(www.)?}Domain-name`) && PathPrefix(`/`)"`. With this both www and direct domain will be identified.